# tweetsharp GetAccessToken returns null

Tags: twitter

I am having a problem . I am using tweetsharp and It's working fine but about 5% of the requests for authentication the GetAccessToken method returns "?" which is caused by the querystring returned null for the TwitterResponse.

here is my code.

> TwitterService service = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);

```
        var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oAuthToken };

        OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oAuthVerifier);



        service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);

        //we'll get the user.
        TwitterUser user = service.VerifyCredentials(new VerifyCredentialsOptions() { IncludeEntities = true, SkipStatus = false });
```

user is returned null in this code , any help is appreciated . Thanks alot.